# TreeNode focused always

Tags: java, swing, matlab, focus, treenode

I have a uitree structure and use MultipleSelectionNodes property actived. I always have two nodes selected. I need to fix the selection on one of them permanently while the other can change by mouse selection. How I can achieve that?

Comment: Do you mean "I need to fix the _selection_ on one of them..."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure that a particular tree node is always selected, you can [write a tree selection listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/treeselectionlistener.html) that will unconditionally select the desired tree node whenever the selection changes. This will have the effect of keeping any tree nodes permanently selected.

```
tree.addTreeSelectionListener(new TreeSelectionListener(){
    @Override
    public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent e) {
        // set tree selection paths that include a path to your permanent nodes
    }
});
```

- [How to Use Trees](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html#select)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. However, my major problem to use your solution is that I do not know Java programming (I am programming with MATLAB).

Comment: @jfpeji: Oh, I'm sorry, I thought you were working with a Java `JTree`! Well perhaps you can do the same thing (add a selection listener) with Matlab.

Comment: Yes, you are right again. I use a Java jtree along with a Matlab uitree component (my code is based on a code that I saw in [UndocumentedMatlab](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/) ) but I do not know Java.